# Unable to locate package firmware-b43-installer (Debian)?

Tags: linux, debian, wifi, firmware

0

I have a laptop that I installed Debian(buster) onto that has no GUI also known as (CLI). But for some reason, I can't install **firmware-b43-installer** it comes up with this error `E: Unable to locate package firmware-b43-installer` I have a BCM4312 network chip. I followed this tutorial on how to install the firmware https://wiki.debian.org/bcm43xx I looked around for a solution for hours but couldn't find a working one. I also downloaded a non-official iso from https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/10.7.0+nonfree/amd64/bt-cd/

but when I made a bootable USB with it and installed Debian it seemed like nothing was changed from the original one, the firmware wasn't installed. I have installed `wpasupplicant`, `wireless-tools`, `network-manager` to see if the firmware was installed but if I typed nmcli device wifi list nothing would come up! so clearly this is a firmware issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging around I have found a method that works! this method only works for these Broadcom wireless network cards :**BCM4311-, BCM4312-, BCM4313-, BCM4321-, BCM4322-, BCM43142-, BCM43224-, BCM43225-, BCM43227-, BCM43228-, BCM4331-, BCM4360-, and BCM4352-**

figure out what WLAN card you have to see if it's compatible with this method:

`lspci -nn | grep Network`

[The output look something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dijss.png)

then install all the required packages:

`sudo apt-get install wpasupplicant`

`sudo apt-get install wireless-tools`

`sudo apt-get install network-manager`

`systemctl enable NetworkManager`

`systemctl start NetworkManager`

`sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome`

`systemctl reboot`

After restart edit **sources.list** using nano and add `main contrib non-free` on every line. (press CTRL+O to save and CTRL+X to exit)
`sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

And reboot the computer again (`systemctl reboot`)

Install Broadcom drivers

`sudo apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') broadcom-sta-dkms`

`sudo modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac bcma`

`sudo modprobe wl`

After all that is done you will have wifi! to see all the available connections in your area type `nmcli device wifi list` (**if you don't see anything then the installation wasn't done properly**)

To connect to a network type this `nmcli device wifi connect SSID password SSID_password`

for example: `nmcli device wifi connect home-net password homenet123`